# Некорректное отображение числа в Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

[image: Firefox, Chrome]

[image: Microsoft Edge]

В браузерах типа: Firefox, Chrome - значение отображается как INT (900)

Код

```
formatCurrency(amount) {
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
      return 0;
    }

    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
    });

    return formatter.format(amount);
}
```

А в Microsoft Edge - добавляются 2 не нужных мне нуля (900.00), может это какая-то особенность Edge?

Comment: В JS нету INT. Покажите код.

Comment: По картинке без кода нельзя на это ответить. Вероятно в функции, убирающей лишние нули, записано что-то, что не поддерживает Edge...

Comment: formatCurrency(amount) {
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
      return 0;
    }

    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
    });

    return formatter.format(amount);
  }

Comment: у меня не воспроизводится проблема в EDGE. В какой версии ты проверял? Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0 - работает как описано.

Comment: @Grundy, https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4A7S.png

Comment: @АннаЕрошина, https://i.imgur.com/2l5Y9p5.png

Comment: @АннаЕрошина, повторю вопрос:  В какой версии была проверка? А все, вижу. Как минимум версии различаются.

Comment: @Grundy, На скрине показано: 44.17763.

Comment: @АннаЕрошина, да, увидел потом. как я указал выше - версии отличаются.

Comment: @Grundy, Thanks, KO! Мелкомягкие опять что-то сломали в обновлениях.

Comment: @АннаЕрошина, это пока вопрос, стоит посмотреть документацию

Answer (score 0):

В общем заменил старую функцию на эту

```
function numberWithCommas(x) { return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); }
```

и всё гуд, так что тема может быть закрытой.
И скорее всего да, в старой функции было что-то что не поддерживал Edge.

Comment: Но ведь это не формирование валюты, а просто разделение разрядов. Проще вырезать оставшиеся нули регуляркой из уже сформированной строки.